# Restore Oracle Database excluding some tablespaces

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I want to restore a backup in cold full (without archivelog) made with RMAN in another server and I do not want to do a full restore but partial, that is to restore only some tablespaces ... I have read that during the backup it can be configured to exclude some tablespaces of this but in this case what I need is ... already with the full backup do a restore of the database excluding certain tablespaces.
Is it possible to do this? it's an Oracle 9i

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RESTORE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96565/rcmsynta46.htm)

> Use an optional SKIP TABLESPACE 'tablespace_name' argument to avoid
>   restoring specified tablespaces, which is useful when you want to
>   avoid restoring tablespaces containing temporary data.
>
> If you specify SKIP FOREVER TABLESPACE, then RMAN specifies the DROP
>   option of ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE ... OFFLINE when taking the
>   datafiles that belong to the tablespace offline before the restore.
>   The DROP option indicates that RMAN does not intend to recover these
>   files and intends to drop their tablespaces from the database after
>   the database is opened again. In other words, FOREVER indicates that
>   RMAN never intends to do anything with the skipped tablespaces again.

Example:

```
RESTORE DATABASE SKIP FOREVER TABLESPACE TOOLS, EXAMPLE;
```